# What does the lower left pane in OllyDbg displays?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have assembled the following code using NASM:

```
global _start

section .data
    var1 DD 0xA1A2A3A4        ; 4 bytes
    var2 DD 0xB1B2B3B4        ; 4 bytes
section .bss
    var3: RESD 1              ; 4 bytes

section .text
_start:
    mov DWORD [var3], 0xC1C2C3C4
```

I opened the file in OllyDbg and made it execute the instruction: `mov DWORD [var3], 0xC1C2C3C4`.

This is the state of the lower left pane in OllyDbg after executing this instruction:

[image]

What I want to know is what does the lower left pane displays? does it display the data section and the bss section of a process?

If so, then is the size of the data section of a process depends on how many bytes allocated in the data section (in this case 8 bytes)?

Answer (score 1):

The lower section display `Memory` so you can ask it do display whatever portion you want. By default it focuses on data section. You can check that by opening `Memory Map` window in Olly and checking the addresses.

[image]

But, as I said, you can use 'Go to' command and ask this to show you any mapped part. As for the minimum size I would say that the probably the default minimum is `1000h` even if you have less.

Comment: Do the variables declared in the `section .bss` in NASM gets loaded in the data section of a process and not in the bss section of a process?

Comment: I have a bit different behavior than yours as in my case the var3 is located in .bss section and not in .data. What does your memory map looks like?

Comment: The data section starts at address 0x01182000 and its size is 0x1000 bytes (and so `var3` is part of the data section).

Comment: well, if I compile your code I get var3 in .bss section as you specified. Only if I comment it out I do get the same as you show in Olly.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best approach here. You're not providing anything more then here. At least include how you're building the app (any non-default switches)? What tool do you use to get the exe? ld from MinGW?

Comment: maybe also put a link there to this one?