# Do the variables declared in the section .bss in NASM gets loaded in the data section of a process and not in the bss section of a process?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have assembled the following code using NASM:

```
global _start

section .data
    var1 DD 0xA1A2A3A4        ; 4 bytes
    var2 DD 0xB1B2B3B4        ; 4 bytes
section .bss
    var3: RESD 1              ; 4 bytes

section .text
_start:
    mov DWORD [var3], 0xC1C2C3C4
```

I opened the file in OllyDbg and made it execute the instruction: `mov DWORD [var3], 0xC1C2C3C4`.

This is the state of the lower left pane in OllyDbg after executing this instruction, along with the memory map:

[image]

As you can see, the data section starts at address 0x00F02000 and its size is 0x1000 bytes (and so `var3` is part of the data section).

---

**Edit:**

I created the object file using the following command:

```
nasm -f win32 D:\1.asm
```

To create the EXE file, I used the following command using the Visual C++ 2010 linker:

```
link D:\1.obj /OUT:D:\1.exe /ENTRY:start /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: afaik windows page size is 4k, perhaps nasm combined data and bss to one single section, since all 3 variables fit into one single page

Comment: I don't see any reason why .data+.bss sections can't be one part after loading the binary into memory, they are almost the same thing, except the .data needs initialization values (and that affects only the loading, not runtime).

Comment: I did the same here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024323/what-does-the-lower-left-pane-in-ollydbg-displays/45025468?noredirect=1#comment77032552_45025468) and got var3 in .bss. But I use ld (from MinGW) to link the exe. If I use link.exe (but from VS 2015) I get the same result as OP. So it's linker dependent

Answer (score 4):

This is an optimization performed by Microsoft's linker.

The PE format specification requires that VirtualSize bytes be allocated for each section. VirtualSize is typically 4 KB, the file alignment multiple and the size of a memory page on Windows. Because your `.data` section is less than 4 KB, the uninitialized data can be fit easily after that, occupying the "slack" space.

If a separate `.bss` section were to be introduced, then this would make the binary larger and increase the load time for no compelling reason. The linker is choosing to merge the `.data` and `.bss` sections together into one.

This additional data (that would have otherwise gone into a `.bss` section) does *not* increase the raw size of the `.data` section because this data does not actually need to be stored anywhere in the binary. Thus, it has essentially the same effect as `.bss`.

As [Paweł Łukasik observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029393/do-the-variables-declared-in-the-section-bss-in-nasm-gets-loaded-in-the-data-se/45032461#comment77034698_45029393), MinGW's linker does not perform this same optimization.

Borland's TLINK (probably only of historical interest now) never emitted a `.bss` section. It always extended the virtual size of the `.data` section.

Comment: is there anywhere this behaviour described or is it only by observation?

Comment: I've only observed it. I looked briefly while composing this answer for an authoritative document confirming it, but I didn't find one. *Very* few of the implementation details for LINK are documented, presumably by design.

Comment: thx, for the info!

Comment: Is the `.bss` section in Windows truly uninitialized?  In Linux, it's guaranteed to be zero-initialized.  In Linux, the data segment of a process is a read-write private mapping of that part of the file, so anything in the file after the initialized data would show up in process memory.  Does Windows copy the initialized part of the data segment into a zeroed page or something, to get zeros after the initialized read-write data?  (That would make the data pages "dirty" at process startup)

Comment: @Peter No, `.bss` is zero-initialized on Windows. That's guaranteed, of course. The visible behavior is identical with this optimization. It's just that you're getting it for free when you merge `.bss` into the "slack" space of `.data`, since that's getting zero-padded out to the 4-byte boundary anyway. But I guess you already found Ross's answer that speaks to that on the duplicate question!

Comment: Yup, found it when I went looking for answers to my question.  I still find it weird that people talk about the BSS as "uninitialized".  There are apparently systems where the kernel doesn't zero the BSS, and CRT startup code has to do that before calling main().  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss claims that "embedded software" is like that.  If DOS was like that, history would explain why Windows people say the BSS is "uninitialized".  Any proper multi-user OS with protected memory and multiple privilege levels has to avoid leaking data by letting user-space have pages with stale garbage.)

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly, COM files were like that (which were DOS, but inherited from CP/M before that). After it was loaded into memory, all of the space after it basically became your `.bss` section. I don't think referring to it as "uninitialized" is that historical, though. MASM uses "uninitialized" for the variables you declare with question marks (even though it's silly, because everybody knows they're actually zero-initialized), and even [NASM's documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.5) for Win32 says "bss declares an uninitialized data section". @Peter

Comment: Ah, yes, and [NASM has this](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.2) to say about COM files: *"The BSS (uninitialized data) section does not take up space in the .COM file itself: instead, addresses of BSS items are resolved to point at space beyond the end of the file, on the grounds that this will be free memory when the program is run. Therefore you should not rely on your BSS being initialized to all zeros when you run."* That's what I was thinking of. I knew I'd read it somewhere more recently than an old copy of "Undocumented DOS" or whatever.

Comment: I wonder if "uninitialized" really did mean "filled with garbage" when MASM's `(?)` syntax and terminology were created?  Once zeroed BSS started to become a thing, there was probably a time when you had to worry about whether it was going to be zeroed or not, but now the meaning of "uninitialized" has changed to "differently-initialized" with zeros.  And then this usage made its way into NASM docs/terminology.  Or maybe I'm wrong, and most people don't think it's weird to talk about memory being uninitialized even after explicitly zeroing it with a `rep stos` during process startup.

Comment: I do have a habit of making up my own terminology or definitions, according to how I think things should be, though.  :P  To me, it's the difference between `static int a[10]` vs. automatic storage `int a[10]` with automatic storage inside a function.  Or between mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)/calloc vs. malloc or alloca.  Static arrays or other fresh memory from the kernel are never filled with random garbage, even it's never been touched to wire the pages into the process's page table.  "Initialized" data doesn't mean touched either, since it can be cold on disk.

Comment: Although it is almost certainly true that MASM's syntax and terminology originally date from the DOS/COM era, I think the reason it's so persistent today is because "uninitialized" is taken to mean just that your program hasn't initialized it. It's merely an implementation detail that the OS pre-zeros it, and that's mainly done for security like you said. I mean, most non-C languages implicitly zero all local variables, but people still commonly speak of those as being "uninitialized" when you haven't explicitly initialized them to a meaningful value.